# Portability and impure behavior of Haskell programs

Tags: haskell

My understanding is that unless code evaluates to so called `bottom` then referential transparency holds in Haskell.

But things happen in real world. Memory is finite, threads may get interrupted, asynchronous exceptions get thrown, spurious interrupts may wake thread, signals, division by zero and so on...

I'm not sure what exceptions mean in Haskell exactly. I understand that programmer and hardware errors are the cause of exceptions. I'll use word 'situation' to describe exceptions and any other observable program behaviour that cannot be handled in pure code (e.g. reasons for my program terminating).

I understand every non-pure situation is to be handled in `IO` as long runtime continues to execute program. And that includes catching exceptions from pure code. So far I learned that I should use `catchAny` to prevent having my program terminate if possible. Is it special to `GHC` in any way? Which runtime situations is it guaranteed to "catch" and which not?

In general, for what areas of impure situations Haskell specification guaranteed APIs for programs to detect and handle in portable way? What is left to implementation and architecture?

Comment: Well... have you looked in the specification yourself? It's quite readable, and, as language specifications go, very short.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you have concerns about being portable to compilers other than GHC. That's a noble goal; but practically, most people don't bother to try that unless they have a good reason (e.g. a specific other compiler that they want to target). The result is that most of Hackage is probably not particularly portable to strictly standards-conformant compilers. Not to discourage you from that goal; just as a heads-up of something to watch for as you write your code.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive specification of what *Haskell* guarantees is [the Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/). This defines the syntax and meaning of the language itself, and also specifies a tiny, tiny set of standard libraries that a compliant computer or interpreter is supposed to provide.

In particular, `System.IO.Error` is specified by the Report. It contains the `ioError` function, which throws a specified I/O exception, and the functions `try` and `catch`, which *only* deal with I/O exceptions. Any other type of exception is completely unaffected.

Now, *GHC* provides `Control.Exception`, which defines a whole heap of extra types and functions for dealing with all sorts of exceptions — arithmetic errors (e.g., divide by zero), out of memory, infinite loop, deadlock, user interrupt (i.e., you pressed Ctrl+C), and so on. This is all GHC-specific and in principle non-portable.

Note that in reality, GHC basically is *the only* production-grade compiler. Once upon a time there were others, but they all seem to have faded into obscurity. In practice, GHC is the only compiler that anybody bothers targetting (unless they're doing something really special). As Daniel Wagner points out, a sizable chunk of Hackage will only compile with GHC.

If you're interested in knowing more about portability, I'd suggest you ask a more focused question. If GHC exception handling is confusing you, ask a more specific question about that.

If you're asking abort portability across operating systems... GHC implements this stuff identically on all the platforms it supports.